# Why aren't these two byte operations equal?

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer

I have the following code:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(totalLength);
bb.putShort(3);
bb.putShort(0);

bb.putInt(3 << 15 + 0);
```

I don't understand why putting the two short values into the byte buffer isn't the same as the second operation

Comment: You need to shift 16, as others have stated, but why do `+ 0`? It doesn't do anything.

Comment: There are no byte operations here. There are (1) two short operations and (2) one int operation, on a different value. The 15 should be 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `bb.putInt(3 << 16 + 0)` instead:)

You could also inspect your `ByteBuffer` with:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bb.array()));
```